# How do I properly structure a package with sub packages in Go where a single type will be the receiver on most of the methods?

Tags: go, package

I'm currently in the design stage of writing a utility library that will make interaction with the [x-go-binding](http://code.google.com/p/x-go-binding/) a bit easier. (I've done this before with Python and xpyb.) For example, it will help with querying information defined in the [EWMH spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) and binding keys to callback functions. (And much more.) So as my initial idea for a package layout, consider:

- xutil

  - ewmh
  - keybind

Where each is its own package. (Similar to how the standard library's image package is setup.)

What's unique about my situation is that almost every x-go-binding call requires some combination of an xgb connection object or a root window identifier. Therefore, it makes sense to me to store this information in a struct like so:

```
type XUtilConnection struct {
    conn xgb.Conn
    root xgb.Id
    // a few other things, like a mapping of events to callbacks
}
```

So that I'd have a factory that could be used like so:

```
xconn = xutil.NewXUtilConnection(blah blah)
```

And it could be used like:

```
xconn.get_active_window()
xconn.bind_key("Shift-a", my_callback_fun)
```

There may also be functions like:

```
keybind.get_keycode("a")
ewmh.get_atom("_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW")
```

My problem of course is that receivers, to my knowledge, can only be of types that have been declared in the same package. If I separate my packages, I cannot use my XUtilConnection type as a receiver in any of my sub-packages.

I suspect that my answer is going to be making this one big package separated into different logical files, but I fear that this might lead to namespace clutter. (For example, implementing the EWMH spec is probably on the order of 100+ functions.)

I am also aware that I could define a new container type in each sub-package for my XUtilConnection object. (I've heard that this should be a struct containing a single member XUtilConnection to avoid casting.) But this seems like a really messy situation to me, and would prevent the kind of semantics I'd like. (i.e., using an XUtilConnection struct to call methods in several different modules.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use [embedding](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).

```
In package xutil:

  type XUtilConnection struct {
      *ewmh.EWMH        // Embed all methods of *ewmh.EWMH
      *keybind.KeyBind  // Embed all methods of *keybind.KeyBind
  }

In package xutil/ewmh:

  type EWMH struct {
      Conn xgb.Conn
      Root xgb.Id
      // and any additional fields that are needed
  }

  // Some EWMH methods:
  func (e *EWMH) GetAtom(name string) { ... }
  func (e *EWMH) ...

In package xutil/keybind:

  type KeyBind struct {
      Conn xgb.Conn
      Root xgb.Id
      // and any additional fields that are needed
  }

  // Some keybind methods:
  func (k *KeyBind) GetKeyCode(s string) { ... }
  func (k *KeyBind) ...
```

This will enable you to directly call `EWMH`'s and `KeyBind`'s methods on values of type `*XUtilConnection`:

```
var c *XUtilConnection = ...
c.GetAtom("_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW")  // Call (*emwh.EWMH).GetAtom(string)
c.GetKeyCode("a")                // Call (*keybind.KeyBind).GetKeyCode(string)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without redefining my struct in each of the packages? (It will always be the same.)

Comment: So I see two major problems with this approach: 1) I must re-create these structs in every package, and 2) if my ewmh package wants to talk to my keybind package, things become even more clumsy because I'm doing embedding on two layers.

It honestly feels really gross. I think putting everything into one package may be less gross. Any other ideas?

Comment: 2) I didn't see any indication in your question that ewmh package wants to talk to keybind.

Comment: Mea culpa. I've marked your response as the answer, since I didn't mention that constraint. (I still don't know if I would have used it---re-declaring the same struct in several modules feels awful.) With that said, do you have any other ideas for how I might structure my package hierarchy other than what I've already mentioned? (One big package or passing around my struct as a parameter to each function.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly the problem (I'm confused by seeing package names where they seem to be discussed as method receivers?), but I guess passing around an interface instead of the [*]struct would enable satisfying it from within any package. One can also always do something like (totally untested code):

```
package foo

type Foo interface { Bar(); Baz() }

----
package qux

import "foo"

type qux struct { foo.Foo; myStuff t }

func Foo(f foo.Foo) foo.Foo {
    return qux{f, &t{}}
}

func (q qux) Bar() {
    // smthg
}
```

To e.g. "override" `f.Bar` in package `qux` and "inherit" `f.Baz()` unaltered.

Comment: My bad---I don't think I was clear enough. What I meant was, the 'ewmh' package would have *both* methods that use a '*XUtilConnection' as a receiver and regular functions like 'ewmh.do_something_without_XUtilConnection'.

With that said, I don't think interfaces work. Atom responded with type embedding---which I hadn't known could work with structs. My problem is "I have some state that I need to pass around to my packages, and the easiest way to do that is to make it a receiver in methods that need it." I don't think interfaces help me.